# How to delay opening of Colorbox iframe popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, colorbox

How would I add a delay (e.g 2 seconds) to my colorbox popup of an iframe

Here's my js, which is cookie-based

```
if (document.cookie.indexOf('colorframe=true') === -1) {
var expires = new Date();
expires.setDate(expires.getDate()+1);
document.cookie = "colorframe=true; escKey=true; expires="+expires.toUTCString();

(function($){
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $.colorbox({escKey:true,innerWidth:475,innerHeight:470,html:'<iframe width=475 height=470 src=http://www.mysite.com/popup-page frameborder=0 border=0 allowfullscreen></iframe>'});
    });
  }(jQuery)
)};
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
 setTimeout(function () {
     $.colorbox({
         escKey: true,
         innerWidth: 475,
         innerHeight: 470,
         html: '<iframe width=475 height=470 src=http://www.mysite.com/popup-page frameborder=0 border=0 allowfullscreen></iframe>'
     });
 }, 2000);
```

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot. I was just missing a semicolon in there.